# What is the relation between dot product and torque?

Tags: vectors, torque

1. what is the relation between dot product and torque?
2. what is the objective of dot product in torque?
3. what do we benefit from getting it?

Comment: It's not clear to my why you think a mathematical operation (the dot product) is related to a physical quantity (torque).

Comment: There is no relation b/w torque and dot product.

Comment: No research effort.

Answer (score 1):

We use cross product in finding the torque.
Torque= F × d and not F.d . 
The torque gives the moment of the force about the point. It is one of the basics of Rotational Mechanics.
When  we calculate the rate of change of torque we get the change in angular momentum.
Rotation without torque is like translation without force !